# Take user input and put paste it in an other field java

Tags: java, swing

I create an app that when you run it you get a panel in order to put the log in details.

This app after connect automatically to some other online tool follow some steps.
In this steps must paste the login details that user put at the panel.

How i can do it?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel mlabel = new JLabel("Please provide login to SCMgr",JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel uLabel = new JLabel("User ID:",JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel pLabel = new JLabel("Password:",JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel pPlatform = new JLabel("Platform:",JLabel.LEFT);
JPanel buttonField = new JPanel(new GridLayout (1,3));
JPanel userArea =  new JPanel(new GridLayout (0,3));
JPanel passArea =  new JPanel(new GridLayout (0,3));
JPanel platformArea =  new JPanel(new GridLayout (0,3));
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout (0,1));
buttonField.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JButton confirm =new JButton("OK");
confirm.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new mouseClick());
buttonField.add(confirm);
App.insertText = new JTextField(20);
App.insertPass = new JPasswordField(20);
App.insertPlatform = new JTextField(20);
frame.add(mlabel);
userArea.add(uLabel);
userArea.add(insertText);
passArea.add(pLabel);
passArea.add(insertPass);
platformArea.add(pPlatform);
platformArea.add(insertPlatform);
frame.add(userArea);
frame.add(passArea);
frame.add(platformArea);
frame.add(buttonField);
frame.setSize(300,200);
App.credGet = false;
frame.setVisible(true);     
while (App.credGet != true) {
    if (App.un != "" && App.pw != "" && App.platform != ""){
        //frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        App.credGet = true;
    }
}
```

And after this app connect to the other tool is following the bellow steps.

```
psess.GetPS().SendKeys("claim", 24, 5);
Thread.sleep(1000);

psess.GetPS().SendKeys("[enter]");
Thread.sleep(1000);

psess.GetPS().SendKeys("name", 20, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
psess.GetPS().SendKeys("Password", 21, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
psess.GetPS().SendKeys("[enter]");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Where is it failing?  Is anything happening at all?  My guess is that you need to set focus on your first field before you can insert "claim".

Comment: Please tell us what is failing. Thank you

Comment: When i run it as it is at the "name" field the app put  the word name and not the provided name from the panel, the same for password.

Comment: in which text field you are getting name and password from user, `App.insertText` and `App.insertPass` or else..??

Comment: Yes there i am getting from uses the details and after i want this details to be pasted  after the "claim" command, (claim  is the first input that the tool need in order to go to the log in page so i put the app to put "claim" and then i can't paste the user details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending `"name"` and `"Password"` as hardcoded `String`s. You need to get name from text field where user had entered his own name and password.

So change following lines

```
psess.GetPS().SendKeys("name", 20, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
psess.GetPS().SendKeys("Password", 21, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

to

```
psess.GetPS().SendKeys(App.insertText.getText(), 20, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
psess.GetPS().SendKeys(App.insertPass.getText(), 21, 16);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

it'll work.

Comment: Yes is working Thank you all for helping me!!!  I am new with Java and always i stack.